# How to display a price if found and another if not found? AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have two tables created by me. I created a form for the second table. I have to add testing data to the form so the Price field will be populated automatically based on the following logic:

- check if the ItemId is available in the first Table
- If found, display the price of the item from the first table
- If not found, display the standard price of the item (Product information management/ Common > Relased products, select a product and on Sell Tab > Price unit.

I tried the following display method but when I choose the ItemId it shows me only 1 or only the first table value and the rest Items which are not found the value 0.

```
display Price price()
{

    HC_ClubAxEx1 hcex1;
    InventTableModule inventTableModule;

    select PriceUnit from inventTableModule;

    if (this.ItemId == hcex1.ItemId)
    {

        this.Price = hcex1.Price;
        select Price from hcex1;
    }
    else
    {
        this.Price = inventTableModule.PriceUnit;
    }
    return this.Price;
}
```

Please help

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/using-the-display-method-modifier

Comment: I tried using a Display method, but it only shows me either the first table price either the Price unit Price

Comment: There are multiple problems, fx. using hcex1.ItemId without selecting hcex1, and selecting  inventTableModule without where conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you need to check the display method:

*This command, return always the first value:*

select PriceUnit from inventTableModule;

```
display Price price()
{

   HC_ClubAxEx1 hcex1;
   InventTableModule inventTableModule;

   // In the same way you need to select hcex1 Table by query:
   //Example:
    select hcex1 where hcex1.MyField == 'yourValue...'

if (this.ItemId == hcex1.ItemId)
{
    // Try to check in debug mode, if the current hcex1 record follow your logic
    this.Price = hcex1.Price;

    // The below code line it's not necessary for you.
    //Need to select the record before to use it
    //select Price from hcex1;
}
else
{
    // select PriceUnit from inventTableModule;
    // You need to create a right select
    //Example below:

    // Need to select the record by 
    //current ItemId or by your logic.
    select PriceUnit from inventTableModule
    where inventTableModule.ItemId == this.ItemId; 

    this.Price = inventTableModule.PriceUnit;
}
return this.Price;
}
```

Following the other people, I try to recommend you to read these guides:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/select-statement-syntax

https://dynamicsaxswapt.wordpress.com/2015/10/01/select-statements-in-ax-2012/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/select-statement-examples

Have a nice day.